# Deserializing a collection with XmlSerialize results in empty collection

Tags: c#, xml, collections, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestPrice>
  <Price>
    <A>A</A>
    <B>B</B>
    <C>C</C>     
    <Intervals>
      <Interval>
        <A>A</A>
        <B>B</B>
        <C>C</C>
      </Interval>
      <Interval>
        <A>A</A>
        <B>B</B>
        <C>C</C>
      </Interval>
    </Intervals>
  </Price>
</TestPrice>
```

And I have three classes defined to deserialize this into an object graph:

```
public class TestPrice
{
    private List<Price> _prices = new List<Price>();
    public List<Price> Price 
    { 
        get { return _prices; }
        set { _prices = value; }
    }
}

public class Price
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    private List<Interval> _intervals = new List<Interval>();
    public List<Interval> Intervals
    {
        get { return _intervals; }
        set { _intervals = value; }
    }
}

public class Interval
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

I can deserialize each part ok. That is, I can do:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Price));
var priceEntity = ((Price)(serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
```

And `priceEntity` is correctly initialized with the XML data contained in `stringReader`, including the `List<Interval> Intervals`. However if I try to deserialize a `TestPrice` instance, it always comes up with an empty `List<Price> Price`.

If I change the definition of `TestPrice` like this:

```
public class TestPrice
{
    public Price Price { get; set; } 
}
```

It works. but of course my XSD defines Price as a sequence. I have other entities deserializing just fine, but they don't include sequences in the root element. Is there a limitation that I'm unaware of? Should I include some sort of metadata in `TestPrice`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just decorate your Price collection with `[XmlElement]`:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Price")]
public List<Price> Price
{
    get { return _prices; }
    set { _prices = value; }
}
```

Also you seem to be deserializing `Price`, whereas the root tag in your XML is `TestPrice`. So, here's a full example:

```
public class TestPrice
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Price")]
    public List<Price> Price { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public List<Interval> Intervals { get; set; }
}

public class Interval
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<TestPrice>
  <Price>
    <A>A</A>
    <B>B</B>
    <C>C</C>
    <Intervals>
      <Interval>
        <A>A</A>
        <B>B</B>
        <C>C</C>
      </Interval>
      <Interval>
        <A>A</A>
        <B>B</B>
        <C>C</C>
      </Interval>
    </Intervals>
  </Price>
</TestPrice>";

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestPrice));
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
        { 
            var priceEntity = (TestPrice)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            foreach (var price in priceEntity.Price)
            {
                 // do something with the price
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I decorated the price collection as suggested and executed your example. Still I get back an empty Price collection. BTW, why are you passing a new XmlReader instance to the serializer instead of the one you already have in xmlReader?

Comment: @Cesar, sorry, that was a mistake with the reader. I have fixed my sample. It should work now.

Comment: Funny, I run your exact same code and it works. But if I adapt it to my actual code, I still get the same result. Anyway at least I know it should work, so I'm marking it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record: I don't know what I was doing wrong, but Drain's answer here is correct. Finally got it to work :)